# Removing some words in capitals but not the ones with smaller lower case

Tags: python, regex

I have a really long text file who looks like this :

```
'a_lot(icl>how)', '', 'TO', 'A', 'VERY', 'GREAT', 'DEGREE', 'OR', 'EXTENT', 'WE', 'ENJOYED', 'OURSELVES', 'A', 'LOT', 'beaucoup', '{CAT(CATADV)}', '', 'a_lot(icl>how)', '', 'TO', 'A', 'VERY', 'GREAT', 'DEGREE', 'OR', 'EXTENT', 'WE', 'ENJOYED', 'OURSELVES', 'A', 'LOT', 'cher', '{CAT(CATADV)}'
```

What I want to do with Python Regex is to delete all capital words as `'TO', 'A', 'VERY', 'GREAT', 'DEGREE', 'OR', 'EXTENT', 'WE', 'ENJOYED', 'OURSELVES', 'A', 'LOT',`.

How can I do this with a regex while maintaining words as `beaucoup` or `cher` (french lower words) and '{CAT(CATADV)}'?

To be clearer, I want my output to be :

```
 'a_lot(icl>how)', '', 'beaucoup', '{CAT(CATADV)}', '', 'a_lot(icl>how)', 'cher', '{CAT(CATADV)}'
```

Comment: [A-Z] will match capitals. [a-z] will match lowercase. Test it out at regex101.com

Comment: Your code does not delete anything, it just fails to print some words. If you want to print all words, your question makes no sense.

Comment: do not want to print the words.. I am sorry, I updated my questions, my code was wrong.. Just delete the upper case English words and maintain the French lower ones –

Comment: what you asking for is `detect the language and delete everything except the english words with uppercase and french word with lower case` is what am getting. If you want to detect language then you have to use some language detect library

Comment: There is a `langdetect` library, a lot of others, but all of them are bad at identifying single word input language.

Comment: You seem to be confusing things by adding English and French to the requirements... when it appears that what you want is to remove any words in capitals but not command strings in capitals (you seem to want to retain {CAT(CATADV)})... the question is unfortunately unclear in it's aims.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 import enchant
 d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
 list = ['a_lot(icl>how)', '', 'TO', 'A', 'VERY', 'GREAT', 'DEGREE', 'OR', 'EXTENT', 'WE', 'ENJOYED', 'OURSELVES', 'A', 'LOT', 'beaucoup', '{CAT(CATADV)}', '', 'a_lot(icl>how)', '', 'TO', 'A', 'VERY', 'GREAT', 'DEGREE', 'OR', 'EXTENT', 'WE', 'ENJOYED', 'OURSELVES', 'A', 'LOT', 'cher', '{CAT(CATADV)}']

 list_of_words = [word for word in list if not d.check(word)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are hoping to achieve here. If the task is to only print words which are upper case, try

```
for word in words:
    if all(x.isupper() for x in word):
        print(word)
```

If you insist on using a regex, try

```
regex = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]+$')
for word in words:
    if regex.match(word):
        print(word)
```

This will not print words which contain upper case and some other symbols which are not lower case; if you want that, perhaps explore some other useful predicates or simply try `not x.islower()` instead of `x.isupper()`.